# ¿Como implemento y configuro una app en android studio, para que se pueda utilizar el SDK de mercado pago?

Tags: java, android-studio, mercadopago, sdk

Ya investigue en varios sitios de **Mercado Pago Developer**, pero me sigue tirando estos errores, y si alguien conoce algún vídeo o alguna pagina web que explique mas detallado este SDK, seria de gran ayuda.

Este error es el que me resalta a la hora a de **Iniciara el** *checkout* **de la aplicación**, me tira este error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y ademas a la hora de copilar la aplicacion me resalta los siguientes errores.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pagina donde me guie=  https://mercadopago.github.io/px-android/v2.html

Gracias por su atencion!

Comment: Acá te pueden ayudar con los errores (que no mencionas) con tu código (que tampoco incluyes). No te van a recomendar videos ni páginas. Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta pronto.

Answer (score 1):

yo pase por ese error , directamente lo solucione pero con la version 4 que seria la ultima https://github.com/mercadopago/px-android en esa pagina te guia mejor.

En caso que te genere un error de bootstrap o algo asi, en app/build.gradle deberas agregar:

compileOptions {

```
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
```

}